# How to make and use an modulized xml file of LinearLayout

Tags: android

I want to make a modulized LinearLayout Xml file, so that I can use it in serveral fragment.

To do this, what should I do?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `include` tag. Let's create 2 files in `layout` directory

**FIRST**

`res > layout > first_element.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**SECOND**

`res > layout > second_element.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="FIRST"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="SECOND"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

And after that you can reuse them in third layout file using `include` tag:

**THIRD**

`res > layout > main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/first_element"/>

    <include layout="@layout/second_element"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you can expect output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But how can I do the same thing in java file? I mean using the modulized xml file in java file.